# Have a button floating in front of a List View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view, android-button

I would like to have a button permanently floating on top of a scrollable ListView in a fragment.  I have tried using FrameLayouts, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and more, but nothing will work.

Here is my base code I'm working off:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--        New Project Button-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_profile_project_relLayoutButton">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_profile_project_newProject_button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
        android:text="@string/project_new_project_button"
        android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_button"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<!--        List View-->
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_profile_project_listView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
```

The Android Studio design view 'understands' what I'm trying to do, but when I run the app only the New Project button appears, or nothing.

[image]

Anyone know how to get a floating button in front of a ListView?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Only creates a layout with a Constraint view group and inside your list and your floating button, thats all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `ListView` Above the `RelativeLayout` with the button. The top view in a layout is the view at the bottom of the layout so moving the listview to the top of the layout file makes it the bottom view

Answer (score 1):

Well you say

> Android Studio design view 'understands', but when I run the app only
> the New Project button appears, or nothing

might be possible you need to check code of your list view setup.

However there are many ways to achieve a `FAB` on top of `ListView`. Simplest one to
Using `FrameLayout`as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ..................................../>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ..................................../>

</FrameLayout>
```

Happy Coding !